# Script to get list of Build number for all Azure Release Pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, shell, azure-devops

I am looking for script/command to get list of Build numbers of all Azure Release pipelines. Does anyone know any way?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Releases - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST api to get a list of releases:

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0
```

The script looks like:

```
Param(
   [string]$org = "orgName",
   [string]$projectName = "projectName",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = " ",
   [string]$token = "PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
write-host $WorkitemType

$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$org/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Write-Host "$($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for reverting. what is the user here? I understand that we are using PAT in Token

Comment: The user can be anything, you could use as I wrote here.

Comment: Actually I need list specifically for all Release numbers and this script lists all details of pipeline.

Comment: I am looking for command that can give build in format like: Pipeline A- Release no. 1
Pipeline B - Release no.2

Comment: Do you mean YAML build or classic release pipeline? The script has list all releases of classic release pipelines. You could get all release IDs, names, ect.

Comment: Getting result as shown below. But I am only looking for command to display only Release number for Releases in a particular folder. e.g. Pipeline A- Release no. 1
2021-04-08T17:21:23.7920768Z   "count": 50,
2021-04-08T17:21:23.7921426Z   "value": [
2021-04-08T17:21:23.7922269Z       "id": 3657,
2021-04-08T17:21:23.7923671Z       "name": "Release-xx_xx_xxxx",
2021-04-08T17:21:23.7924147Z       "status": "active",
     "createdOn": "2021-04-08T17:20:27.19Z",      "modifiedOn": "2021-04-08T17:20:27.19Z",      "modifiedBy": {
 "displayName": "abcd"

Comment: There is no default command to get such information. You need to filter the information from the script above. For example, you could get release IDs via `$result.value.id`.

Comment: not yet :( How to get release Id via $result.value.id

Comment: Have you checked the script in my reply? You should be able to get $result from my script.

Comment: Yes I am using below mentioned script but where to use $result.value.id

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
write-host $WorkitemType

$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$org/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Write-Host "$($result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

Comment: All information you need has included in $result. Then you need to do is filter the information. For example, you could get release IDs in last of the script `Write-Host "$($result.value.id | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`.